# How to correctly select or lay out Excel data for a chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a set of data regarding my recent Bitcoin investment and I'd like to plot growth on a chart.

Unfortunately, with the way the data is laid out on my spreadsheet, I can't seem to get the chart to make any sense.

What I'm looking for is a chart similar to what I've got, but where the line in the chart represents the Growth Percentage values.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

What's the concept that I'm missing behind the layout or selection of the data for the chart?

Comment: How are you creating the chart? The data works fine for me.

Comment: I've tried a number of ways. Highlighted A5-B7, click Insert>Chart>Line Chart

Comment: Are your dates in date format?

Comment: They are now, graph still appears as depicted

Comment: Seems it was the graph I was using (100% stacked line) which was wrong.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer to help others in the future?